# Can I consume a server-paged OData result in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, odata, data-paging

I'd like to consume a server-paged OData result.

That means, the JSON code includes an element

```
"__next": "http://server/odata.svc/table?$skiptoken=guid'4dda1cd9-7eff-423f-a314-08edf26a22e8'"
```

How do I do this in ASP.NET MVC? I see quite a few examples for consuming OData, but none handles paged data.

I'm quite new to both OData and MVC, so please be as obvious as possible in the answers. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main way of consuming OData in .NET is with the  WCF Data Services client library. In Visual Studio, you can right click on a project, and select "Add Service Reference" to get started. That "Add Service Reference" uses the WCF Data Services client library under the hood.  For general information on how to use the client library, check out the MSDN documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668772.aspx

A caveat, though: the JSON you posted (with `"__next"`) is the old OData JSON format, sometimes referred to as "Verbose JSON".  The WCF Data Services client does not have support for this format. It only supports Atom and the new JSON format.  As long as your server is able to support either Atom or the new v3 JSON, that shouldn't be a problem for you.

As for your actual question, you can use the `.GetContinuation()` method on a `QueryOperationResponse` object. For example:

```
// "DemoService" is the auto-generated subclass of DataServiceContext created when you run "Add Service Reference"
DemoService context = new DemoService(new Uri(<url to the service root>));
var firstPage = context.Customers.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<Customer>;
var token = firstPage.GetContinuation();
if (token != null)
    var secondPage = context.Execute<Customer>(token);
```

Obviously, you'd probably want to turn this into a loop, but that should give you a basic idea of the API usage. For more information, see this page on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358711.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jen, that helps a lot! Now, your example collects all result pages at once but for a web application wouldn't it be better to provide a continuation link to the visitor? Is there anything ready-made to bind the continuation address to a paging link in the view? The problem of course being that the continuation link then should not link directly to the OData stream, but to a new view page.

Comment: That's a great question, but I don't have a great answer for you (partially because I'm just not very familiar with data binding).  I don't know of any continuation mechanisms other than GetContinuation(), so any data binding nice-ness would have to be  custom code you write layered on top of GetContinuation().

Comment: Thinking more about it, my guess is there is no ready-made paging solution connected to the OData continuation, especially since the continuation is forward-only. Users expect forward- and backward-paging.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing MVC and OData, I would highly recommend that do this with Web API and not mess with all the WCF configuration intricacies of WCF. Here's what your controller would like like with MVC Web API: (very simple and clean).

```
public class ProductController : EntitySetController<Product, int>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public ProductController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public override IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().Query().Get();
    }

    protected override Product GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        return _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().FindById(key);
    }

    protected override Product UpdateEntity(int key, Product update)
    {
        update.State = ObjectState.Modified;
        _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().Update(update);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
        return update;
    }

    public override void Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        _unitOfWork.Repository<Product>().Delete(key);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _unitOfWork.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

You see this post, for full walk-through **http://blog.longle.net/2013/06/18/mvc-4-web-api-odata-entity-framework-kendo-ui-grid-datasource-with-mvvm**.